# How to make content wrapper "on top" of css grid

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm working on a site layout using a two-column CSS grid, which looks somewhat like this. It works fine and all the content centers perfectly in each div. The cells with "bg" just have a background image. Each grid cell "touches" the borders of the browser window.

```
+--------+--------+
|  text  |   bg   |
+--------+--------+
|   bg   |  text  |
+--------+--------+
|       text      |
+-----------------+
```

However, is there an easy way to wrap & center the content so that it doesn't go beyond a certain width? I could target individual paragraphs to align left or right depending on their cells, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this? The brackets are the "wrapper".

```
+--------+--------+
|   [text|  bg]   |
+--------+--------+
|   [bg  |text]   |
+--------+--------+
|   [   text  ]   |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @Michael_B
https://codepen.io/arjenbokhoven/pen/oymYRe

Succinctly: I want all text to be constrained to the same width as the bottom paragraphs spanning 2 columns, so that the single cells have extra white space on their respective left and right sides.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a wrapper around the entire two column grid and add some padding to the left and right of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fcfcfc;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  background: #fff;
}

.gridbg {
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.px-2 {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Vestibulum felis ligula, placerat non felis id, hendrerit interdum nunc. Fusce finibus, sapien ac blandit ultrices, est tortor viverra turpis, et venenatis ipsum purus id magna. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="gridbg">
        </div>
        <div class="px-2">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Vestibulum felis ligula, placerat non felis id, hendrerit interdum nunc. Fusce finibus, sapien ac blandit ultrices, est tortor viverra turpis, et venenatis ipsum purus id magna. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work because it will wrap the whole grid. I want the grid to be full-width but the content wrapped, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: My two-column grid layout is full-width, and some grid cells contain paragraphs of text, while others have only a background image. I would prefer my paragraphs to be constrained to an overall content width, and not full-width like my grid layout. Essentially, I want all my text to be wrapped.

Comment: I now understand what you are looking for. Probably, you would need javascript to set the desired widths.